# How to ONLY replace the next two characters

Tags: javascript, string, time, timezone, date-conversion

I am trying to reset a ISO time to local time, but I am having some trouble converting it.

Currently, I:

```js
// incoming ISO date
let date = new Date('2021-11-08T20:31:23.746Z');

// 1. get timezone offset in hours
const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

// 2. calculate local hour
let localHour = date.toISOString().split('T')[1].substring(0, 2) - offset;

// 3. calculate local time
let localTime = date.toISOString().replace(/[T-:]/, localHour);

console.log(localTime);

// ISO Date
// 2021-11-08T20:31:23.746Z (original)
// 2021-11-08T13:23.746Z (local timezone)
```

In step 3, I am trying to only replace the first two characters after 'T', however, this is not the correct solution with Regex.

Comment: The regexp should be `T..` to match `T` and the following 2 characters.

Comment: This won't work if the time difference changes the date.

Answer (score 1):

The Date constructor automatically converts the date to your locale after parsing.

```js
// incoming ISO date
let date = new Date('2021-11-08T20:31:23.746Z');

const res = date.toLocaleString().replaceAll('/', '-').split(', ').join('T')
console.log(res)

// ISO Date
// 2021-11-08T20:31:23.746Z (original)
// 2021-11-08T13:23.746Z (local timezone)
```

Comment: When I run it, it gives me `'Mon Nov 08 2021 13:31:23 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)'. How can I convert it back to ISO, but with the local time?

Comment: @TylerMorales I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Stop right there and don't do this. Date management is hard. You are going to shoot yourself in the foot. Use a library, for example [dayjs](https://day.js.org/).

```
dayjs(date).local().toDate()
```